# How to download beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I am taking an info storage and retrieval class, and to complete an assignment we need to download and use the beautifulsoup package for python. I haven't used Python in years, so I'm very rusty and cannot seem to figure out how to download a Python package. I'm using Python 3 and have Windows 10.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+download+beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: that's not the issue. Read the question `windows command line (cmd) doesn't even acknowledge that I have python downloaded.`